# Confusing behavior of File.dirname

Tags: ruby

I have written a couple of small Ruby scripts for system administration using Ruby 1.9.3. In one script I use:

```
File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

to get the directory of the script file. This returns a relative path, however when I call the script from a second script `File.dirname` returns an absolute path.

[Ruby Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-dirname) lists an absolute return path in its example whereas I found a discussion on [Ruby Forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/143383) where a user says `dirname` should only return a relative path.

I am using the suggested solution from Ruby Forums to use `File.expand_path` to always get the absolute path like this:

```
File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

but is there a way to make the behaviour of `dirname` consistent?

---

UPDATE:

To expand on Janathan Cairs answer, I made two scripts:

s1.rb:

```
puts "External script __FILE__: #{File.dirname(__FILE__)}"
```

s0.rb:

```
puts "Local script __FILE__: #{File.dirname(__FILE__)}"
require './s1.rb'
```

Running ./s0.rb gives the following output:

```
Local script __FILE__: .
External script __FILE__: /home/kenneth/Pictures/wp/rip_vault
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`File.dirname` should return an absolute path if given an absolute path, and a relative path if given a relative path:

```
File.dirname('/home/jon/test.rb') # => '/home/jon'
File.dirname('test.rb') # => '.'
```

`__FILE__` returns the name of the current script, which is therefore a relative path from the current directory. That means you should always use `expand_path` if you want to get the absolute path with `File.dirname(__FILE__)`.

**NB** Ruby 2.0.0 [introduces the `__dir__` constant](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/)

Comment: Yes, that explains it. And the lesson learned would then be that invoking scripts from other scripts makes __FILE__ an absolute path. I guess that seems reasonable enough.

Answer (score 4):

If you already upgraded to [Ruby 2.0](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/), you can use the new constant

```
__dir__
```

otherwise you can use

```
File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)
```

which is shorter than

```
File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

[File.expand_path documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path)